# How to create a list out of excel sheet values with Python?

Tags: python, list

I'm pretty new to all this python and Excel things.
I have a really big excel sheet with 1 million rows, my goal is to create a list with a few for list (I think that is what I need to do) and the problem is the follow:

I have something like this:

[image]

I want to add to a list all the POINT_Y and POINT_X (gps coordinates) where the objectid is the same and when the objectid changes I want to add those values to another list.

I only manage to get the data from the excel, my problem is in the construction of the lists.

```
import pandas
from shapely.geometry import Point

polygon_sheet =pandas.read_excel("C:...\coords.xlsx")
for row in polygon_sheet.index:
    data = (polygon_sheet['POINT_Y'][row]) + ", " + \
           (polygon_sheet['POINT_X'][row])
```

I'm sure I need a nested for loop but I don't know how to obtain what I want, that is something like this:

`id1 = [[41.15226404, 25.41327506], [41.15221095, 25.41363158], [41.15220779, 25.41395401], [...(all coords from id1)]]`

`id2= [[41.11617356, 25.53488120], [41.11541559, 25.53517417], [41.11494893, 25.53531324], [...(all coords from id2]]`

And so on until all ID's are iterated.

Hope I could explain what I expect correctly.
Appreciate any help

Comment: Look up Pandas groupby.

Comment: where do you want to store those output lists ? to another pandas df ? or in a dict ?

Comment: @rusu_ro1 in a dict.
For each ID I need a dict?

Comment: if you want to store in a dict than each id is a key from dict

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can apply a custom function over each row in order to create a dict with your desired output:

```
from collections import defaultdict

id_points = defaultdict(list)

def extrct_points(row):
    o_id, point_x, point_y = row
    id_points[o_id].append([point_x, point_y])

polygon_sheet.apply(extrct_points, axis=1)
```

for example:

```
polygon_sheet = pd.DataFrame({'OBJECTID': [1, 1,  2, 2, 2, 3], 'POINT_X':[0.23, 0.123, 0.1, 0.1, 0.2, 1],
                  'POINT_Y':[0.223, 0.3123, 0.11, 0.11, 0.22, 11]})
```

[image]

```
from pprint import pprint

polygon_sheet.apply(extrct_points, axis=1)

pprint(id_points)
```

output:

```
defaultdict(<class 'list'>,
            {1.0: [[0.23, 0.223], [0.123, 0.3123]],
             2.0: [[0.1, 0.11], [0.1, 0.11], [0.2, 0.22]],
             3.0: [[1.0, 11.0]]})
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a dict of lists.Try something like this:

```
import pandas
from shapely.geometry import Point

dt = {}
polygon_sheet =pandas.read_excel("C:...\coords.xlsx")
for row in polygon_sheet.index:
    try:
        dt[polygon_sheet['ID'][row]] += [[polygon_sheet['POINT_Y'][row], polygon_sheet['POINT_X'][row]]]
    except:
        dt.update({polygon_sheet['ID'][row]: [[polygon_sheet['POINT_Y'][row], polygon_sheet['POINT_X'][row]]]})

print(dt)
```